# Automatically adjusting abstract from one to two columns and back

Tags: abstract

I am editing the latex template that has a custom abstract environment. 
I would like to keep the width of (0.65) in two column mode, but to change to full width in single column mode.

Would someone please advise on how to make this adjustment automatically. Original code is below:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{   
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}  
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}  
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\ \textcolor{Blue}{\textbf{\abstractname}}}  
{\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\end{minipage}}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it figured out. I am using conditional

```
\makeatletter 
 \if@twocolumn  
   \hfill\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}  
 \else
    \hfill\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
 \fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: This requires a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](http://goo.gl/HYwLd).